Pass a Variable to an Open Form
I want to pass a variable to another form which opens with OpenForm.  My form open event does not seem to be called.  Maybe I am not referring to it correctly.  The print statement in the first subroutine is correct, but the Debug.Print "A" never happens.   Also, once this variable is passed to the new form, how do I use it in an SQL statment?
Private Sub DataObjectsWhereUsed_Click()
    Dim dataId As String
    dataId = Me.DataObjectsList.Column(2)
    Debug.Print dataId
    DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="ProcessByDataObject", OpenArgs:=dataId
End Sub

Public Sub ProcessByDataObject_Open()
    Dim dataObject As Variant
    Debug.Print "A"
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        dataObject.Value = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
    
End Sub


Do you get what you want with Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer) or Private Sub Form_Load() instead of Public Sub ProcessByDataObject_Open()?

They don't debug.print "A".   Form_Open works on the main form, but not the sub form

Your code and your comment are confusing. How is a subform involved? Do you mean it is really a second standalone form? What do you want second form to do with passed value? Maybe this should be a form/subform arrangement.

Your Public Sub ProcessByDataObject_Open() is never called.
Use the Form_Open event of the ProcessByDataObject form:
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim dataObject As Variant

    Debug.Print "A"
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        dataObject.Value = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
    
End Sub

